# Please make the reputation graph two-tone

Tags: feature-request, reputation, daily-reputation-limit, reputation-graph

A suggestion for the rep graph:

Currently, it has green columns for each days' rep, and a line indicating the 200-point limit.

As we know, it's quite easy to get >200 points on a day as only certain types of activity counts toward that 200 point limit, but the graph gives no visibility of how close one is/was to the limit on a given day

The graph shows us a total for our points, but doesn't show us how many of those points counted toward the 200 point limit.

I suggest changing the graph from a single green bar into a two-tone stacked bar, with one segment at the bottom for the points that counted toward the 200 limit and a second segment above it for any other points earned.

This would allow us to see at a glance both the total points and also how many points were earned within that 200 point limit.

(The actual colours of the two segments isn't relevant, but I'd suggest two tones of green)

Comment: *it's quite easy to get >200 points on a day* well not that much for us new users!

Comment: @fedorqui - "easy" in the sense that it could be achieved with a single answer on a question with a large bounty.

Comment: Yes, I see your point. I +1 the request, can be nice to see that.

Comment: Achieving 200+ is not that common amongst most users. I think this will be needless complexity in the system. Plus, we will then start getting questions from new users, "what do the different colors mean?", "whats the mortarboard badge?", etc.

Comment: @Spudley: I see you very often overpar that score.... `:P`

Comment: @AsheeshR Vote to close =)

Comment: @fedorqui: Well not that much for most users!

Comment: "The graph shows us a total for our points, but doesn't show us how many of those points counted toward the 200 point limit." Wait, don't all points count towards the 200, but only *some* can go over it?

Comment: @M.NightDemonbobby No. If you get 19 upvotes, then an accept, you've gained 205 reputation, but only 190 of that counts towards the 200 limit; you'd still get full value for your next upvote.

Comment: @AsheeshR I'm not sure potentially getting questions from people who don't read the available information is ever a valid reason to vote against a feature request.